# Data (numbers) dissappearing from another class' method

Tags: c#, class, methods, xna

I've been having this problem lately - In my main class Game1.cs I call upon a method inside my loot.cs to determine which loot the player should be given. The method basically adds say, 5 coins when called . My problem is that whenever the method has been called and it continues to execute and update stuff in my Game1.cs, all coins gotten through that method are gone.

I ran the debugger all the way, so I know that the player actually got the coins, but that the coins were removed afterwards.

Full Game1.cs (Warning, wall of text)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;
using System.IO;

namespace Innovationally 
{
enum GameState
{
    TITLESCREEN,
    HELPSCREEN,
    PLAYING,
    WON,
    LOST
}
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    GameState gameState = GameState.PLAYING;

    //PLAYER STATS
    Player player;
    KeyboardState currentKeyboardState;
    KeyboardState previousKeyboardState;
    float playerMoveSpeed;

    //COLLISION STATS
    Rectangle kollision;
    int bHit;

    //LEVEL STATS
    int level_number = 0;
    int loadlevel = 0;
    Texture2D hud, level0, level1, level2, level3, level4, level5;
    Vector2 levelPos;

    //ROOM STATS
    List<int> tile_life = new List<int>();
    Texture2D tile_gfx, stairsUp, stairsDown;
    List<Vector2> tile_position = new List<Vector2>();
    List<int> tile_type = new List<int>();
    int antlabb = 0;
    int antvapen = 0;
    int antpolis = 0;
    int antwavers = 0;
    int researchSpan;

    //MISC
    SpriteFont font;
    Loot loot;

    //GAMEPLAY STATS
    TimeSpan timeElapsed;

    public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 800;
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 900;
    } 
    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        player = new Player();
        playerMoveSpeed = 4.0f;
        levelPos.X = 0;
        levelPos.Y = 0;
        loot = new Loot();
        researchSpan = 120;
        base.Initialize();
    }
    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

        Vector2 playerPosition = new Vector2(430, 450);
        //LEVEL STATS
        LaddaLevel(level_number);
        level0 = Content.Load<Texture2D>("level0");
        level1 = Content.Load<Texture2D>("level1");
        level2 = Content.Load<Texture2D>("level2");
        level3 = Content.Load<Texture2D>("level3");
        level4 = Content.Load<Texture2D>("level4");
        level5 = Content.Load<Texture2D>("level5");
        hud = Content.Load<Texture2D>("hud");

        //ROOM STATS
        tile_gfx = Content.Load<Texture2D>("tile");
        stairsUp = Content.Load<Texture2D>("stairsUp");
        stairsDown = Content.Load<Texture2D>("stairsDown");

        font = Content.Load<SpriteFont>("SpriteFont1");
        player.Initialize(Content.Load<Texture2D>("Leftplayer"), playerPosition);
    }
    public void LaddaLevel(int nummer)
    {
        StreamReader SR = new StreamReader(nummer.ToString());

        string bana = SR.ReadToEnd();
        SR.Close();
        int temp_positionY = 0;
        int temp_positionX = 0;

        tile_position.Clear(); 
        tile_type.Clear();    
        tile_life.Clear(); 

        for (int i = 0; i < bana.Length; i++)
        {
            switch (bana[i])
            {
                case ' ':
                    temp_positionX++;
                    break;
                case '0':
                    tile_life.Add(loot.myRnd.Next(8));
                    tile_position.Add(new Vector2((temp_positionX * 100), (temp_positionY * 100)));
                    temp_positionX++;
                    tile_type.Add(int.Parse(bana[i].ToString()));
                    break;
                case '8': 
                    tile_position.Add(new Vector2((temp_positionX * 100), (temp_positionY * 100)));
                    temp_positionX++;
                    tile_type.Add(int.Parse(bana[i].ToString()));
                    tile_life.Add(8);
                    break;
                case '9': 
                    tile_position.Add(new Vector2((temp_positionX * 100), (temp_positionY * 100)));
                    temp_positionX++;
                    tile_type.Add(int.Parse(bana[i].ToString()));
                    tile_life.Add(9);
                    break;
                case '\n':
                    temp_positionY++;
                    temp_positionX = 0;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    protected override void UnloadContent()
    {
    }
    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
            this.Exit();
        previousKeyboardState = currentKeyboardState;
        currentKeyboardState = Keyboard.GetState();
        if (currentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape) && previousKeyboardState.IsKeyUp(Keys.Escape))
            this.Exit();

        switch (gameState)
        {
            case GameState.TITLESCREEN:
                if (currentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.S) && previousKeyboardState.IsKeyUp(Keys.S))
                    gameState = GameState.PLAYING;
                if (currentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.H) && previousKeyboardState.IsKeyUp(Keys.H))
                    gameState = GameState.HELPSCREEN;
                break;
            case GameState.HELPSCREEN:
                if (currentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.B) && previousKeyboardState.IsKeyUp(Keys.B))
                    gameState = GameState.TITLESCREEN;
                break;
            case GameState.PLAYING:
                timeElapsed += gameTime.ElapsedGameTime;
                UpdatePlayer(gameTime);
                UpdateCollisions(gameTime);
                break;
            case GameState.LOST:
                if (currentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.S) && previousKeyboardState.IsKeyUp(Keys.S))
                {
                    loadlevel = 0;
                    gameState = GameState.PLAYING;
                }
                break;
        }
        base.Update(gameTime);
    }
    private void UpdatePlayer(GameTime gameTime)
    {

        if (currentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Left))
        {
            player.angle = (float)Math.PI * 1.5f;
            player.Position.X -= playerMoveSpeed;
        }
        if (currentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right))
        {
            player.angle = (float)Math.PI / 2;
            player.Position.X += playerMoveSpeed;
        }
        if (currentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
        {
            player.angle = (float)Math.PI * 2;
            player.Position.Y -= playerMoveSpeed;
        }
        if (currentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Down))
        {
            player.angle = (float)Math.PI;
            player.Position.Y += playerMoveSpeed;
        }
        if (player.health <= 0)
            gameState = GameState.LOST;
    }
    public void UpdateResearchCenters(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        if (antlabb >= 1)
            researchSpan -= (gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Seconds * antlabb);

        //if (researchSpan <= 0)
          //  d
    }
    public void UpdateCollisions(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        Rectangle playerBox = new Rectangle((int)player.Position.X - 20, (int)player.Position.Y - 20, 40, 37);
        Rectangle levelBox = new Rectangle(0, 0, 900, 800);

        for (int i = 0; i < tile_position.Count; i++)
        {
            Rectangle tileBox = new Rectangle((int)tile_position[i].X, (int)tile_position[i].Y, 100, 100);
            if (playerBox.Intersects(tileBox))
            {
                if (tile_life[i] <= 9)
                {
                    if (tile_life[i] == 9 && currentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space)) 
                    {
                        loadlevel += 1;
                        LaddaLevel(loadlevel);
                    }
                    else if (tile_life[i] == 8 && currentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space))
                    {
                        loadlevel -= 1;
                        LaddaLevel(loadlevel);
                    }
                    else if (tile_life[i] == 7 && currentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space))
                    {
                        loot.RandomLoot();
                        tile_life[i] = 70; 
                    }
                    else if (tile_life[i] == 6 && currentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space))
                    {
                        tile_life[i] = 60;
                    }
                    else if (tile_life[i] == 60 && currentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space) && (player.mvgelever >= 1 || player.problemelever >= 1 || player.normalaelever >= 1))
                    {
                        if (player.mvgelever >= 1)
                        {
                            player.mvgelever -= 1;
                            tile_life[i] = 600;
                        }
                        else if (player.normalaelever >= 1)
                        {
                            player.normalaelever -= 1;
                            tile_life[i] = 6000;
                        }
                        else if (player.problemelever >= 1)
                        {
                            player.problemelever -= 1;
                            tile_life[i] = 60000;
                        }

                        antlabb += 1;
                    }
                    else if ((tile_life[i] == 600 || tile_life[i] == 6000 || tile_life[i] == 60000) && currentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(Keys.Space) && previousKeyboardState.IsKeyUp(Keys.Space))
                    {
                        antlabb -= 1;
                        if (tile_life[i] == 600)
                            player.mvgelever += 1;
                        if (tile_life[i] == 6000)
                            player.mvgelever += 1;
                        if (tile_life[i] == 60000)
                            player.mvgelever += 1;
                        tile_life[i] = 60;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //Överlappar vi?
        kollision = Intersection(playerBox, levelBox);

        if (kollision.Width > 0 && kollision.Height > 0)
        {
            Rectangle r1 = Normalize(playerBox, kollision);
            Rectangle r2 = Normalize(levelBox, kollision);
            if (loadlevel == 0)
                bHit = TestCollision(player.PlayerTexture, r1, level0, r2);
            if (loadlevel == 1)
                bHit = TestCollision(player.PlayerTexture, r1, level1, r2);
            if (loadlevel == 2)
                bHit = TestCollision(player.PlayerTexture, r1, level2, r2);
            if (loadlevel == 3)
                bHit = TestCollision(player.PlayerTexture, r1, level3, r2);
            if (loadlevel == 4)
                bHit = TestCollision(player.PlayerTexture, r1, level4, r2);
            if (loadlevel == 5)
                bHit = TestCollision(player.PlayerTexture, r1, level5, r2);
        }
        else
        {
            bHit = 0;
        }

        if (bHit == 1 || bHit == 2)
        {
            if (player.angle == (float)Math.PI)
                player.Position.Y -= playerMoveSpeed;
            if (player.angle == (float)Math.PI * 2)
                player.Position.Y += playerMoveSpeed;
            if (player.angle == (float)Math.PI / 2)
                player.Position.X -= playerMoveSpeed;
            if (player.angle == (float)Math.PI * 1.5f)
                player.Position.X += playerMoveSpeed;
        }
    }
    public static Rectangle Intersection(Rectangle r1, Rectangle r2)
    {
        int x1 = Math.Max(r1.Left, r2.Left);
        int y1 = Math.Max(r1.Top, r2.Top);
        int x2 = Math.Min(r1.Right, r2.Right);
        int y2 = Math.Min(r1.Bottom, r2.Bottom);

        if ((x2 >= x1) && (y2 >= y1))
        {
            return new Rectangle(x1, y1, x2 - x1, y2 - y1);
        }
        return Rectangle.Empty;
    }

    public static Rectangle Normalize(Rectangle reference, Rectangle overlap)
    {
        //Räkna ut en rektangel som kan användas relativt till referensrektangeln
        return new Rectangle(
          overlap.X - reference.X,
          overlap.Y - reference.Y,
          overlap.Width,
          overlap.Height);
    }

    public static int TestCollision(Texture2D t1, Rectangle r1, Texture2D t2, Rectangle r2)
    {
        //Beräkna hur många pixlar som finns i området som ska undersökas
        int pixelCount = r1.Width * r1.Height;
        uint[] texture1Pixels = new uint[pixelCount];
        uint[] texture2Pixels = new uint[pixelCount];

        //Kopiera ut pixlarna från båda områdena
        t1.GetData(0, r1, texture1Pixels, 0, pixelCount);
        t2.GetData(0, r2, texture2Pixels, 0, pixelCount);

        //Jämför om vi har några pixlar som överlappar varandra i områdena
        for (int i = 0; i < pixelCount; ++i)
        {
            if (((texture1Pixels[i] & 0xff000000) > 0) && (texture2Pixels[i] == 0xffC3C3C3))
            {
                return 1;
            }
            if (((texture1Pixels[i] & 0xff000000) > 0) && (texture2Pixels[i] == 0xff000000))
            {
                return 2;
            }
            if (((texture1Pixels[i] & 0xff000000) > 0) && (texture2Pixels[i] == 0xff000000))
            {
                return 1;
            }

        }
        return 0;
    }
    private void DrawHud()
    {
        string timeString = "TIME: " + timeElapsed.Minutes.ToString("00") + ":" + timeElapsed.Seconds.ToString("00");

        spriteBatch.Draw(hud, new Vector2(0, 0), Color.White);
        spriteBatch.DrawString(font, timeString, new Vector2(15, 35), Color.White);
        spriteBatch.DrawString(font, "Level " + (loadlevel + 1), new Vector2(15, 10), Color.White);
        spriteBatch.DrawString(font, "" + player.mvgelever, new Vector2(739, 55), Color.White);
        spriteBatch.DrawString(font, "" + player.problemelever, new Vector2(799, 55), Color.White);
        spriteBatch.DrawString(font, "" + player.normalaelever, new Vector2(859, 55), Color.White);
        spriteBatch.DrawString(font, "" + antwavers, new Vector2(454, 55), Color.White);
        spriteBatch.DrawString(font, "" + antpolis, new Vector2(514, 55), Color.White);
        spriteBatch.DrawString(font, "" + antvapen, new Vector2(574, 55), Color.White);
        spriteBatch.DrawString(font, "" + antlabb, new Vector2(633, 55), Color.White);
        spriteBatch.DrawString(font, "" + player.antkills, new Vector2(348, 55), Color.White);
    }
    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

        spriteBatch.Begin();
        switch (gameState)
        {
            case GameState.TITLESCREEN:
                break;
            case GameState.PLAYING:
                if (loadlevel == 0)
                    spriteBatch.Draw(level0, new Vector2(0, 0), Color.White);
                if (loadlevel == 1)
                    spriteBatch.Draw(level1, new Vector2(0, 0), Color.White);
                if (loadlevel == 2)
                    spriteBatch.Draw(level2, new Vector2(0, 0), Color.White);
                if (loadlevel == 3)
                    spriteBatch.Draw(level3, new Vector2(0, 0), Color.White);
                if (loadlevel == 4)
                    spriteBatch.Draw(level4, new Vector2(0, 0), Color.White);
                if (loadlevel == 5)
                    spriteBatch.Draw(level5, new Vector2(0, 0), Color.White);
                for (int i = 0; i < tile_position.Count; i++)
                {
                    switch (tile_life[i])
                    {
                        case 0: spriteBatch.Draw(tile_gfx, tile_position[i], Color.White);
                            break;
                        case 1: spriteBatch.Draw(tile_gfx, tile_position[i], Color.HotPink);
                            break;
                        case 2: spriteBatch.Draw(tile_gfx, tile_position[i], Color.YellowGreen);
                            break;
                        case 3: spriteBatch.Draw(tile_gfx, tile_position[i], Color.Purple);
                            break;
                        case 4: spriteBatch.Draw(tile_gfx, tile_position[i], Color.Yellow);
                            break;
                        case 5: spriteBatch.Draw(tile_gfx, tile_position[i], Color.Silver);
                            break;
                        case 6: spriteBatch.Draw(tile_gfx, tile_position[i], Color.Gold);
                            break;
                        case 7: spriteBatch.Draw(tile_gfx, tile_position[i], Color.Orange);
                            break;
                        case 70: spriteBatch.Draw(tile_gfx, tile_position[i], Color.DarkOrange);
                            break;
                        case 8: spriteBatch.Draw(stairsDown, tile_position[i], Color.White);
                            break;
                        case 9: spriteBatch.Draw(stairsUp, tile_position[i], Color.White);
                            break;
                    }
                }
                DrawHud();
                player.Draw(spriteBatch);
                break;
        }
        spriteBatch.End();
        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
}
}
```

Loot.cs' RandomLoot() Method:

```
 class Loot
{
    Player player = new Player();
    public Random myRnd = new Random();
    public int primarylootnumber;
    public int secondarylootnumber;
    public int tertiarylootnumber;
    public void RandomLoot()
    {
        primarylootnumber = myRnd.Next(1, 11);
        switch (primarylootnumber)
        {
            case 1:
                player.godis++;
                break;
            case 2:
                player.godis += 3;
                break;
            case 3:
                player.godis += 5;
                break;
            case 4:
                player.normalaelever += 1;
                break;
            case 5:
                player.normalaelever += 2;
                break;
            case 6:
                player.health += 10;
                break;
            case 7:
                player.health += 30;
                break;
            case 8:
                player.health += 50;
                break;
            case 9:
                player.damage += 5;
                break;
            case 10:
                player.damage += 10;
                break;
        }
```

And finally, inside Player.cs:

```
class Player
{
    public int godis, normalaelever, health, damage, maximumhealth, normalaelever, problemelever;
}
```

What is that I have missed?

Comment: Are you recreating the `Loot` object all the time? Every time a new `Loot` object is created, a new `Player` gets created. Perhaps you want the game to instantiate the `Player` and give it by reference to the looting object.

Comment: Wait what? Not sure what you mean. At the top of each class I have a `'Class' 'class' = new 'Class'`, and then I simply use `class.Property` to use them, like `player.coins += 1`

Comment: So, `Game1` creates `Loot`, `Loot` creates `Player`, if I read correctly? Are you sure there is no code that recreates either `Loot` or `Player`?

Comment: @Neophyte `Game1.cs` full code needed for find the issue

Comment: @Damith Added the entire Game1.cs now.

Comment: They're not the same player, try passing player into the `RandomLoot` method and remove the `Player player = new Player()` line. I also think that the `int` types can be made local instead of a field.

Comment: That might be the cause of it? I am quite new to all this, could you please explain further how I would "pass player into the `RandomLoot` method"? And what you mean by making the `int` types local? @Caramiriel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty simple problem here-
The Game1.cs has a player defined, and each Loot object makes up its own player.

This means you have a ton of Players, one of which the Game uses and controls, and then the rest are temporary fake player objects that each coin is using.

You need to define only a single player object:

In Game1.cs, change the "Player player;" to "public static Player player;"

EDIT: And then in Player.cs, change "class Player" to "public class Player"

Then in the loot.cs, change "Player player = new Player();" to "Player player = Game1.player;"

This will ensure you only ever use one player object.

(Note: there are 'better' ways of handling this, such as a passing down the player object reference to the Loot objects init function or whatever. This is the quick and simple way.)

Explanation of the above code: "public" means "Any other class can access this variable." and "static" means "There is only ever one value here, no matter how many times I create the Game1 class." (In this case, despite there only ever being one Game1, the static is used to make it so you can access the variable from the classname.variable, rather than having to first pass down the current Game1 object.)

Other explanation: Every time you do "Class class = new Class();", You are saying "Create a brand new object of this class." A class is like a definition of what something is, EG you define a "Ball" class as anything that is round and bouncy. An object is one instance of this definition. EG, an actual physical ball. But you can also have a second ball, a third, a fourth, etc. that are all still just the same class, but different objects of the same class.

Comment: Sends me error: "Inconsistent accessibility: field type 'MyGame.Player' is less accessible than 'MyGame.Game1.Player'".  Any ideas why?

Comment: @Neophyte - Oh, I forgot. In your Player class, change "class Player" to "public class Player"

Comment: It works now, thanks. Marking this as answer, since it is the only one directly explaining a solution.

Answer (score 0):

you are not setting values for `coins`, what you are doing is set values to godis, normalaelever, health  or  damage

### Update

```
public class Player
{
    public int godis { get; set; }
    public int normalaelever { get; set; }
    public int health { get; set; }
    public int damage { get; set; }
    public int maximumhealth { get; set; }
    public int problemelever { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, okay, you got me. The code is not *exactly* like that, the player class contains values for godis, normalaelever, health etc. too. I'm not stuck because of such a misstake. Fixed it for convinience.

Comment: @Neophyte update your Player class with properties like above

Comment: @Neophyte you have `normalaelever` twise in Player class

Comment: Sorry, another misstype I've done. Normalaelever doesn't occur twice in the actual code. Also, the above code doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Oh I found something new when I ran the debugger a few seconds ago. Whenever I called the RandomLoot() method, all of the stats (godis, damage, health, normalaelever etc) got set to 0, and then they returned to their normal values I had set in the initialize when I jumped out from the method. Odd.